# How to get Pandas Index Position and Name

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking to get the names and index position from a pandas DataFrame and got into a logic as below, Just wondering if there is much better way to deal this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/docs/Credit_Card.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
cols = df.columns
col = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in df.columns if c in cols]
print(pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cols, col)),columns=['index_Name', 'Index_Number']))
```

result output:

```
             index_Name  Index_Number
0        Card Type Code             0
1   Card Type Full Name             1
2          Issuing Bank             2
3           Card Number             3
4    Card Holder's Name             4
5              CVV/CVV2             5
6            Issue Date             6
7           Expiry Date             7
8          Billing Date             8
9              Card PIN             9
10         Credit Limit            10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict` `{name: column_names: number: column_numering}` to create the datafarme.

```
In [591]: pd.DataFrame({'index_Name': df.columns, 'Index_Number': range(len(df.columns))})
Out[591]:
             index_Name  Index_Number
0        Card Type Code             0
1   Card Type Full Name             1
2          Issuing Bank             2
3           Card Number             3
4    Card Holder's Name             4
5              CVV/CVV2             5
6            Issue Date             6
7           Expiry Date             7
8          Billing Date             8
9              Card PIN             9
10         Credit Limit            10
```

Or use

```
In [621]: pd.DataFrame({'index_Name': df.columns}).rename_axis('index_Number').reset_index()
Out[621]:
             index_Name  Index_Number
0        Card Type Code             0
1   Card Type Full Name             1
2          Issuing Bank             2
3           Card Number             3
4    Card Holder's Name             4
5              CVV/CVV2             5
6            Issue Date             6
7           Expiry Date             7
8          Billing Date             8
9              Card PIN             9
10         Credit Limit            10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

print(pd.DataFrame(list(zip(df.columns, 
                            np.arange(len(df.columns)))),
                   columns=['index_Name', 'Index_Number']))
```

Similar with [`numpy.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
print(pd.DataFrame(np.c_[df.columns, np.arange(len(df.columns))],
                   columns=['index_Name', 'Index_Number']))
```

Or:

```
df1 = pd.Series(df.columns).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Index_Number','index_Name']
```

Comment: @pygo - Yes, for better performance is better use in pandas `np.arange` like `range` ;)